# How can I get data from json file using vue js 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to get data from json file, it has just json data.

```
[{"id":81,"body":"There are some reason to fix the issues","created_at":"2017-11-16 11:56:47","updated_at":"2017-11-16 11:56:47"}]
```

I added vue-resource and properly use it as per vue syntax.

```
import vueResource from 'vue-resource'
Vue.use(vueResource)
```

In my userlist component i am trying following script

```
 export default {

    data:function(){
      return {
        list:[],
        car:{
          id:'',
          body:''
        }
      };
    },

    created: function(){
      this.fetchCarList();
    },


    methods:{
      fetchCarList: function(){
        this.$http.get('http://localhost:8080/api.js').then(function(response){
          this.list = response.data
        });
      }

    }
}
```

And this is component HTML loop

```
<ul id="example-1">
    <li v-for="item in list">
        {{ item.body }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have checked `http://localhost:8080/api.js` which is properly returning the data. Also when I am adding the json data in `fetchCarList` method then loop works fine but with get() call it does not working.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Instead of assignment, have you tried logging `response.data` to console within the callback? Do you see the response?

Comment: @Terry Yes I did just now. Console log showing json data properly

Comment: Then I know what your issue is: check my answer :)

Comment: why do an http request? is the json file not on the same server! just import the json file into your js file. `const json = require('./data.json');`

Answer (score 0):

You have a scoping issue: `this` within the callback does not refer to your Vue instance. That is because you are not using ES6 arrow function, i.e.:

```
this.$http.get('http://localhost:8080/api.js').then(response => {
    this.list = response.data
});
```

...which means the outer `this` is not passed in. You will have to proxy that yourself, i.e. `var self = this` on the outside, and then use `self.list = response.data`:

```
var self = this;
this.$http.get('http://localhost:8080/api.js').then(response => {
    self.list = response.data
});
```

Comment: I have tried your instruction but still does not working